# After deleting my phone number from my Facebook profile, what will happen?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, profile

What will happen if I remove my phone number from my Facebook profile?  Do I still continue to get my messages in Messenger?

Comment: This is a mess, please put in more effort when you post a question.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will happen except the following things

- you wont be receiving alert text messages when you are offline.
- you wont be getting birthday alerts as text messages of your friends
- you wont come to know about if someone comments on your wall if you
  remove your number.    because you will be getting text message
  saying someone commented on your post.
- most important is if you register your phone number then you can use
  that for changing    password even if someone tries to change you
  will get sms.

some of the advance usages to know your cirle friends location etc will be disabled.